# Point set topology in R

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}+[0,1]=\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{Q}$ is set of rational numbers. What would be the answer when we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. I don't have any idea how to proceed rigorously.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What is Q+[0,1]?

Comment: @5xum I suppose it's the usual: $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,\ b\in B\}.$ I can't think of anything else it could mean.

Comment: @5xum Possibly OP means a set of sums: $A+B=\{(a+b): a\in A\land b\in B\}$....?

Comment: What is 'adding set of rationals to [0, 1]'...?

Comment: Yes your supposition is correct.

Comment: A+B={a+b,a ∈A,b ∈B}

Comment: @5xum: that is perfectly standard notation

Comment: @user497359: this post lacks the context that we look for. Even when you don't know how to formally proceed, you can explain where you encountered the question, why you think it may be of interest, and the attempts you have already made. Otherwise, the post might appear to be nothing more than a homework problem copied onto this site, which is not what we aim for.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} + [ 0, 1 ] = \mathbb{R}$
Is this. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, then we know $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} + [ 0, 1 ]$, so let $x$ be rational. Considering the binary expansion, let $x = N + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n 2^{-n}$, where $N$ is an integer and $b_n \in \{ 0, 1 \}$, and moreover such that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $b_n = 0$. This is analogous to how in decimal, some numbers have a terminating decimal that can be rewritten with trailing $9$s; we're choosing the one without trailing numbers.

By virtue of the infinite number of times $b_n = 0$, we can make a sequence $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$ such that $b_{n_k} = 0$, and $n_{k + 1} - n_k \geq k!$ for all $k$. Let $t = \sum_{ k = 1 }^{\infty} 2^{-n_k}$. This number has a binary expansion which is $1$ on terms of $(n_k)$ and $0$ elsewhere. The number is irrational because $(n_k)$ is not eventually periodic as a sequence (this is what the growth condition got us). Moreover, $t + x \in [0, 1]$. So we can say $x = -t + (t + x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete @Sami Fersi's answer on $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q + [0,1] =\Bbb R$, let $x \in \Bbb R$.

Now if $x \notin \Bbb Q$ we're done since $x = x + 0$. Otherwise, pick some irrational $0 < y < 1$, e.g. $\frac {\sqrt 2} 2$. Then $x = (x - y) + y$ and it's trivial to show $ x - y \notin \Bbb Q$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $x\in \Bbb R$. $x=x-E(x)+E(x)$ where $E(x)$ is the integer part of $x$. $x-E(x) \in [0,1]$ and $E(x) \in \Bbb Q$ so $x\in \Bbb Q +[0,1]$ thus $\Bbb Q+[0,1]=\Bbb R .$

This proves that $\Bbb Z+[0,1]=\Bbb R$ as well since $E(x) \in \Bbb Z \ \forall x\in \Bbb R$.
With the same idea we can prove that $\Bbb N+[0,1]=\Bbb R_+$ (Here $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,...\}$)

To prove that $(\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q)+[0,1]=\Bbb R$ just notice that $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{E(x)}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{E(x)}{\sqrt{2}}$

If $x\ge 1$ or $x<0$ then $\frac{E(x)}{\sqrt{2}} \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ and so $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \in (\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q) +[0,1]$, otherwise, let $r \in (\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q)\cap [-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}},1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}]$, we have $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+r \in [0,1]$ so $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}=-r+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+r\in (\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q)+[0,1]$

so $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q+[0,1] \forall x\in \Bbb R$ and so $x \in (\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q)+[0,1] \forall x \in \Bbb R$

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify whether you're using the convention that $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @AJY, you're right, I'll add it immediately.

Comment: $\frac 0 {\sqrt 2} - \frac {E(0)} {\sqrt 2} = 0 \notin \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$

Comment: But x-E(x)∈[0,1)

Comment: @cronos2 : I didn't pay attention to the case E(x)=0, I've changed my answer and taken that case into account.